# How can I properly connect to my local Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I'm fairly new with running mongodb.

The confusion I'm having is setting up the mongodb collection. I just cloned a new repository, and I think when I start up mongodb in the terminal, it's pointing to the old repository. I had an experience developer set this up for me so everything needed is installed.

After I did a mongorestore in the new repository:

```
cd ../dlaentdatabase/mongodump
mongorestore --db DLADashboard --drop --gzip --archive=DLADashboard.20160420.gz
```

I run my localhost which reads the following:

```
Mongoose connected to mongodb://localhost/DLADashboard
```

How can I be rest assured that the mongodb is 'talking' with the new mongodump?

Answer (score 0):

You can just go and change filepath in hard disk. If you can't talk with mongodb then, you had talking with new one. if so then change the filepath back to the previous one.